# How to input my username in website using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have the following code to insert my username which works perfectly for a different website. Why does it not translate to the website in my code below?

```
Sub Login_Alb()
    Dim IE As Object, html As Object
    Const USERNAME = "Confidential"
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www3.mainaccount.com/ca/"

        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        html.querySelector("#userName").innerText = USERNAME


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I played around with this and couldn't figure it out - I'm surprised your code doesn't work. We'll need QHarr to inspect! He's the expert on this stuff.